# Slickgrid does not render or populate the JSON data in table / Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slickgrid, populate

below is the `columns` object i have using

```
 columns =[
      {id: "id", name: "ID", field: "id"},
      {id: "rt_assignee", name: "rt_assignee", field: "root_task_assignee"},
      {id: "root_task_id", name: "root_task_id", field: "root_task_id"},
      {id: "root_task_status", name: "root_task_status", field: "root_task_status"},
      {id: "root_task_tracker", name: "root_task_tracker", field: "root_task_tracker"},
      {id: "rt_category", name: "rt_category", field: "rt_category"},
      {id: "rt_priority", name: "rt_priority", field: "rt_priority"},
      {id: "rt_subject", name: "rt_subject", field: "rt_subject"},
      {id: "task_assignee", name: "task_assignee", field: "task_assignee"},
      {id: "task_category", name: "task_category", field: "task_category"},
      {id: "task_id", name: "task_id", field: "task_id"},
      {id: "task_priority", name: "task_priority", field: "task_priority"},
      {id: "task_status", name: "task_status", field: "task_status"},
      {id: "task_subject", name: "task_subject", field: "task_subject"},
      {id: "task_tracker", name: "task_tracker", field: "task_tracker"}
]
```

and this is function `loadData()` with the sample JSON `data` which I tried to populate in the grid

```
function loadData() {
    data = [{   
          "id", "issue_0", 
          "root_task_assignee": "reneym",
          "root_task_id": 123808,
          "root_task_status": "New",
          "root_task_tracker": "Task",
          "rt_category": "PPQA",
          "rt_priority": "Normal",
          "rt_subject": "95-00 Perform PPQA",
          "task_assignee": "reneym",
          "task_category": "PPQA",
          "task_id": 123808,
          "task_priority": "Normal",
          "task_status": "New",
          "task_subject": "95-00 Perform PPQA",
          "task_tracker": "Task"    
      }];
dataView.setItems(data);
}
```

but there is no output the grid is simply blank(but the header appears). And there is no error message.

Code

```
loadData(); 
dataView.setGrouping([]); 
dataView.endUpdate(); 
$("#gridContainer").resizable();
```

Comment: `loadData(); dataView.setGrouping([]);  dataView.endUpdate(); $("#gridContainer").resizable();`  this is what is used

Comment: 1. Please edit additional informations to your question. 2. Show the loadData() function too.

Comment: `dataView.setItems(data);` and this is within the`loadData()` function call

Comment: @kayess I have edited the question

Comment: good, but you still didn't show the grid initialisation/creation command! On first glance, shouldn't the `data` parameter be named `tempData`, that you pass to `dataView.setItems()` ?

Comment: @kayess I am using as it is in this [slick grid example] (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example-grouping.html)

Comment: @kayess I just modified the `columns` and `data`

Comment: @kayess Its not a issue, i have tried both `tempData` and `data` as a parameter in `dataView.setItems()`

Comment: if you post the full code (including the initializataion) I might be able to help.

Comment: @SujalMandal  this is the code I have used [example-grouping](https://ide.c9.io/prem_kumar_e/slickgrid)

Comment: @kayess above i shared the cloud9 link which has the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have quickly crafted you a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kayess/qzhy9vk3/5/) with the setup you mentioned in your question.

The *small* and overlooked problem you had is that, when you are creating a JavaScript [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) you need to use `:` as **separator** when you descibe your *key value pairs*.

So use `:` instead of `,` you had in your `id` field declaration.

---

As an example you had:

```
data = [{   
    "id", "issue_0",
    ...
}];
```

Instead you need:

```
data = [{   
    "id": "issue_0",
    ...
}];
```